# How can I center text in the middle of a site and remove the scrollbar?

Tags: css, center

I need this text in the center of a site but it this alignment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

::selection { opacity:.1; background:rgba(255, 255, 255,0.3) }

body {
background-color:#9999ff;
color:white;
font-family:arial;
font-size:100px;
font-weight:;
}

div.container4 {
height: 10em;
position: relative }
div.container4 p {
margin: 0;

position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }
}

</style>

<div class=container4>
  <p><font style="font-weight:bold;">Project</font> Lavender<br><font style="font-size:60px;">Coming 2019
</div>
```

When i use this a scroll bar appears. I would not like to just have it removed but to make it so it doesn't show up no matter what.
Below is a picture of the scrollbar
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQZwW.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to the body:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: that works but when i'm on another computer its all messed up and dislocated.

Answer (score 0):

how about center tag?
even though it is frowned on

Comment: <center>Your text here...</center>